# Gödel's loophole

Tags: us-constitution

After WWII before Gödel was about to be interviewed in order to get a US citizenship, he had found a loophole in the US constitution which allowed a fascist regime to legally turn the US into a dictatorship. I tried searching it online and only found that  Gödel's loophole is related to article 5 of the US constitution; however, I couldn't find more information about it. So what is Gödel's loophole? Can you explain it to me?

Comment: What do you mean you couldn't find info about it?  There's a Wikipedia page specifically about it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_Loophole#:~:text=G%C3%B6del's%20Loophole%20is%20an%20%22inner,legally%20turned%20into%20a%20dictatorship.

Comment: If you read the Wikipedia page you will see that it says  that the exact nature of Godel's loophole has never been published and isnt known.

Comment: **Your question**, *"So what is Godel's loophole?Can you explain it to me?"*.  **The answer:** *"the exact nature of Godel's loophole has never been published and isnt known."*

Comment: @Volpina So you know that it isn't known, but you are asking us to explain it to you?  I have voted to close as this is going to prompt answers which are people saying "I think it is ..."

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article already linked, the only people who could answer definitively are Gödel himself (died 1978), Oskar Morgenstern (died 1977), and Albert Einstein (died 1955). Anyone else can only speculate, because there's no way to know if the contradiction they find is the one Gödel was thinking of. Wikipedia also quotes someone as calling it "one of the great unsolved problems of constitutional law", so the idea that posting it here would somehow attract an answer that had been overlooked for several decades seems ... a bit optimistic.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The answer may be unknown to Wikipedia, but that does not mean the question is not susceptible to an objectively correct answer, either now or in the future.

Comment: @bdb484 The question isn’t "find a loophole in the Constitution", but "find _the same loophole as Gödel_". While it could be answered objectively (e.g. if one finds a manuscript in Gödel’s archives), that’s a question for history.se, not law.se.

Comment: I agree that that is the relevant question, but this is the first time I've heard anyone say a question doesn't belong here because it asks about something in the past. It's the same as asking, "Find the same loophole *Plessy v. Ferguson* relied on to permit racial segregation despite the Fourteenth Amendment."

Answer (score 3):

[This article](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2010183) lays out what little is known about the putative loophole, thought to depend on problems of "self-reference". (This is because of the nature of Gödel's view on "self-contradiction"). Note that Article V might itself be amendable.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that Gödel's loophole (whatever it was) might have appealed to philosophers, but not so much to political scientists.

All Constitutions can be re-written.  All can be changed.  There is a mechanism through which the entire US Constitution can be re-written. Certainly an Amendment could be written and approved to strike through most of the document and replace the government with a Holy Dictator if enough states supported it.  This is self-evident to anyone with a cursory knowledge of government.

If Gödel thought that he had discovered a textual loophole he might have just been naïve.  Such a change to fundamental interpretation of the Constitution would need to go back to The Federalist Papers, Constitutional Convention discussions, and original founder intent and I doubt he would find such intent there.  Philosophical arguments carry more weight in academia than in a courtroom.